# Perl call a sub routine that exists inside of an array

Tags: perl

I am trying to make a state machine in Perl. To do this I have an array indexed by statenames. I can put subs into this array. Like this:

```
   use constant {
    stInit          => 0,
    stHeader        => 1,
    stSalesHeader   => 2,
    stCatagory      => 3,
    stData          => 4,
    stTotal         => 5,
    stError         => 6, 
};

my $state = stInit;
my @actions;

$actions[stInit] = [sub{logState("Initial state entered",2) }];
$actions[stHeader] = [sub{logState("Header state entered",2) }];
$actions[stSalesHeader] = [sub{logState("Sales header state entered",2) }];
$actions[stCatagory] = [sub{logState("Category state entered",2) }];
$actions[stData] = [sub{logState("Data state entered",2) }];
$actions[stTotal] = [sub{logState("Total state entered",2) }];
```

But then I have no Idea how to call the subroutine. I have tried this

```
$actions[$state]
```

But that appears not to work. Is this possible or am I completely off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really should add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the start of your code, which will find many simple mistakes for you. In this case your code is fine, and you can call your subroutines by using

```
$actions[$state][0]();
```

etc.

But there is no need to put the subroutines within square brackets, which just creates a one-element anonymous array and adds an additional level of indexing (hence the `[0]` in the above line of code. If you wrote code like this instead

```
$actions[stInit] = sub { logState("Initial state entered", 2) };
```

then you would be able to call the subroutines with

```
$actions[$state]();
```

Comment: Using `()` nicely avoids accidentally inheriting `@_` as well, using `&` is a bad habit IMO.

Comment: Indeed. The only non-esoteric use for `&` is to access a reference to a subroutine using `\&mysub`. It has been this way for many years.

Comment: @Borodin, Like `$ref->()`, `&$ref()` doesn't inherit `@_` either.

Comment: @Borodin, `&` is also useful for disabling prototypes. (e.g. `&async($sub)`).

Comment: @Borodin, `&` is also used in `goto &sub;`, `defined &sub` and  `exists &sub`.

Comment: @Borodin: FYI, I've just deleted my answer; yours is better.

Comment: @ikegami: IMO disabling prototypes, using `goto` to a subroutine, and checking the definedness or existence of a subroutine all fall in the category of "esoteric". Very few people will have had reason to do any of them.

Answer (score 2):

On an a slightly different note, have you considered using [`FSA::Rules`](https://metacpan.org/module/FSA%3a%3aRules) to write your state machine? It's fairly powerful, has optional GraphViz output and makes state machines rather easy to write.

Answer (score 1):

To call a subroutine from a reference:

```
&{$actions[$state]}();
```

However, based on your code, @actions does not contain subroutine references, but array references to the declaration of the subroutine.

first, declare the subs as you normally would and then build @actions:

```
$actions[0] = \&stInit;
$actions[1] = \&stHeader;
...and so on
```

Comment: The use of an ampersand when calling subroutines is old-fashioned and very bad practice. Just `$actions[$state]()` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
&{$actions[$state][0]}
```

but I'm not sure why you use an array... If you have just 1 function then

```
$actions[stData] = sub{ ... }
...
&{$actions[$state]}
```

will work. If you really want to execute many functions and use the array, then you can do:

```
map { &{$_}  } @{$actions[$state]};
```

Comment: Yet again, as for the other two answers, use `$actions[$state]()` in all but very old versions of Perl. Also you are committing the sin of using `map` for its side-effects and discarding the result. If you want to do this then you just need `$_->() foreach @{$actions[$state]};`

Answer (score 1):

Drop the extraneous anonymous array creation by removing the square brackets

```
$actions[stInit] = sub{logState("Initial state entered",2) };
```

You can then call the action with

```
$actions[stInit]();
```

If you have an action stored in a variable, e.g.

```
my $action = $actions[$actionID];
```

then you'll need a bit more syntax to make it actually do the call

```
$action->();
```

Then again, you could just use a hash instead of an array

```
my %actions = (
    stInit        => sub { logState("Initial state entered",2) },
    stHeader      => sub { logState("Header state entered",2) },
    stSalesHeader => sub { logState("Sales header state entered",2) },
    stCatagory    => sub { logState("Category state entered",2) },
    stData        => sub { logState("Data state entered",2) },
);
```

which would save you from having to set up constants at the top. You could then call actions with

```
$actions{$state}();
```